# how to add key value pair in the JSON object already declared

Tags: javascript, json

I have declared a JSON Object and added some key value pair in that like:

```
var obj  = {};
```

and added some data into it like:

```
obj = {
"1":"aa",
"2":"bb"
};
```

But I want to add more key value pair in the same object, if I add key value pair same above mentioned then it replace the old one. So could any one please tell me how I can append data in the same JSON Object i.e. obj.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**Could you do the following:**

```
obj = {
    "1":"aa",
    "2":"bb"
};


var newNum = "3";
var newVal = "cc";


obj[newNum] = newVal;



alert(obj["3"]); // this would alert 'cc'
```

Comment: This will result in an exception being thrown.It makes no sense to use `JSON.parse()` on an instantiated JavaScript object.

Comment: Also `.push()` is an array method, and is not available for plain objects.

Comment: you;'re right Pointy - i was hasty in my answer! Have updated with alternative (working) solution. ;-)

Comment: @Vishnu It has nothing to do with nodejs and should work same way in any environment. Please be more specific in your query.

Answer (score 16):

You can use dot notation or bracket notation ...

```
var obj = {};
obj = {
  "1": "aa",
  "2": "bb"
};

obj.another = "valuehere";
obj["3"] = "cc";
```

Answer (score 10):

Object assign copies one or more source objects to the target object.  So we could use `Object.assign` here.

Syntax: `Object.assign(target, ...sources)`

```js
var obj  = {};

Object.assign(obj, {"1":"aa", "2":"bb"})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: This is the best answer especially when you need to add a large object with multiple key value pairs to an existing object.

Answer (score 5):

Example code  for json object:

```js
    var user = {'user':'barney','age':36};
    user["newKey"] = true;
    console.log(user);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="lodash.js"></script>
```

for json array elements

Example code:

```js
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40 }
];

users.map(i=>{i["newKey"] = true});

console.log(users);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi I add key and value to each object

```js
let persons = [
  {
    name : "John Doe Sr",
    age: 30
  },{
    name: "John Doe Jr",
    age : 5
  }
]

function addKeyValue(obj, key, data){
  obj[key] = data;
}
 

let newinfo = persons.map(function(person) {
  return addKeyValue(person, 'newKey', 'newValue');
});

console.log(persons);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add more key value pair in the same object without replacing old ones in following way:

```
var obj = {};

obj = {
"1": "aa",
"2": "bb"
};

obj["3"] = "cc";
```

Below is the code and jsfiddle link to sample demo that will add more key value pairs to the already existed obj on clicking of button:

```
var obj = {
    "1": "aa",
    "2": "bb"
};

var noOfItems = Object.keys(obj).length;

$('#btnAddProperty').on('click', function() {
    noOfItems++;
    obj[noOfItems] = $.trim($('#txtName').val());
    console.log(obj);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shrawanlakhe/78yd9a8L/4/

Answer (score 3):

**Please try following simple operations on a json, insert/update/push:**

```
var movie_json = {
                    "id": 100,
                 };

//to insert new key/value to movie_json
movie_json['name'] = 'Harry Potter';
console.log("new key: " + movie_json);

//to update a key/value in movie_json
movie_json['id'] = 101;
console.log("updated key: " +movie_json);

//adding a json array to movie_json and push a new item.
movie_json['movies']=["The Philosopher's Stone"];
movie_json['movies'].push('The Chamber of Secrets');
console.log(movie_json);
```

Answer (score 0):

possible duplicate , best way to achieve same as stated below:

```
function getKey(key) {
  return `${key}`;
}

var obj = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2", [getKey('key3')]: "value3"};
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47405116/3510511