# Insert Object To Single Object in Javascript JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Good day,

So I'm trying to insert an object to my single javascript json object.

I have this sample result which is called fruits when I enter the value inside `console.log(JSON.stringify(fruits))`

```
{"Apple": {"price": 100}, "Banana": {"price": 120}, "Grapefruit": {"price": 300}}
```

But I need to push or append new fruit which is the `Mango` in this result.

What I tried so far is something like this.

```
fruits.push({"Mango": {"price":350})
console.log(fruits)
```

But apparently, I'm getting an error.

Any help?

Comment: Objects do not have a push method. Consider using either the square bracket notation? `fruits["Mango"] = {"price":350}`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add key value pair in the JSON object already declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527712/how-to-add-key-value-pair-in-the-json-object-already-declared)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ... spread operator.

```
fruits = {...fruits, "Mango": {"price":350}}
```

Comment: but is there a way to show it at the top result?

Comment: What do you mean by the top result?

Answer (score 2):

Your data is stored in an javascript object as property. To add new property to fruits, try this:

```
fruits["Mango"] = { price : 350 };
```

Answer (score 0):

assign() is used to copy objects to a target object

```
Object.assign(fruits,{"Mango" :{ "price" : 350} });
```